# Next.js build and export for template engine

Tags: html, next.js, template-engine

I would like to export my Next.js project for the use with a Template Engine. (In my case "twig") I replaced all the texts in my HTML with the `{{ ... }}` twig markdown. 
When I run `next build && next export` the HTML is generated as intended. The problem now is, that when I render e.g. the "index.html" with the twig renderer the texts are replaced again bei the markdown `{{ ... }}` from the `.../index.js` code. (Since this calls `createElement` and replaces all creates the tags for faster loading)

Now my question is: is it possible to disable the generating of the `.js` file for every page sothat I can change the `.html` file without it being overwritten?

P.S. The build is running as a SSG (Static Site Generator) eventhough I am not using `getInitalProps`, `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` or `getServerSideProps` which I find strange. And I have no configuration in the `next.config.js` file.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Sadly no... I ended up doing a search and place manually. Wasn't too fun...